# what's a better way to read information from TXT and put into list in python

Tags: python

I have a TXT in following form, which is the data for [Knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem):

- `100` in first row represents the total capacity
- `10` in first row represent the number of items
- Then each row contains the value and weight for each item. For example, the second row `9 46` represents an item with 9 in value and 46 in weight.

> 100 10\n 9 46\n 28 31\n 15 42\n 13 19\n 31 48\n 36 11\n 13 27\n 42 17\n 28 19\n 1 31

I use the code below to read the information and put it into separate list.

```py
with open(path) as f:

    capacity,total_number = f.readline().split(' ')
    capacity = int(capacity)
    total_number = int(total_number)
    value_list = [int(x.split(' ')[0]) for x in f.readlines()]
    f.seek(0)
    next(f)
    weight_list = [int(x.split(' ')[1]) for x in f.readlines()]
    assert total_number==len(weight_list)==len(value_list)
```

But it kinds feel redundant in a way.

Ccould anyone help me with improvements on that?

Comment: you can probably use a CSV loader, setting the delimiter to `" "`, no index, and taking the column names as the totals

Comment: `lines = f.readlines()` after the initial `f.readline()`, then use the two list comprehensions with `lines` instead of `f.readlines()`. No need to rewind to the beginning of the file that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can use a list comprehension to cast the entire line to integers at once.
- You can use the [`zip(*...)`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/functions.html#zip) idiom to transpose a list; here, to transpose a list of `[(value, weight), (value, weight), (value, weight)]` pairs to `[value, value, value...]` and `[weight, weight, weight...]`.

```
with open(path) as f:
    capacity, total_number = [int(num) for num in f.readline().split()]
    values_and_weights = [[int(num) for num in l.split()] for l in f.readlines()]
    value_list, weight_list = zip(*values_and_weights)
```

In fact, since all lines are just number pairs,

```
with open(path) as f:
    data = [[int(num) for num in l.split()] for l in f.readlines()]
    capacity, total_number = data.pop(0)  # remove and unpack first line
    value_list, weight_list = zip(*data)
```

is even more succinct.

Comment: Hi AKX, I tried this code, but the output of velue_list and weight_list is tuple instead of list, anyway to change this?

Comment: @JackDuan Cast them to lists. `value_list, weight_list = [list(x) for x in zip(*data)]`